# Riot.js 4, how to mount nested tags

Tags: javascript, riot.js

I'm creating application in Riot.js 4 and using in-browser compilation (for prototyping), everything was working fine in Riot.js 3.
However, when I use nested tags, only the root tag is mounted and not any child tags. If I mount every nested tag separately, they are mounted fine.

Minimal example is here: https://plnkr.co/edit/hxXUvmsjEgE3eDAF

```
<main>
    <p>main tag</p>
    <footer></footer>
</main>

<footer>
    <p>footer</p>
</footer>

riot.mount('main')
```

If I mount also nested component, it works, see here: https://plnkr.co/edit/UDkdZ55ynTYz9uxL

```
riot.mount('main')
riot.mount('footer')
```

What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in riot you cannot use the same name of another existing tag, so, because footer is an [existing tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/HTML/Element/footer) you should change the name of "footer" component and it will work just fine! ;)